# Efficiency issue on Guile SCHEME: member and equal?

Tags: performance, functional-programming, scheme, equality

I am new on SCHEME programming and after some while I succeeded on writing a couple of scripts to deal with long maths formulas.

The issue is that its execution is pretty slow. After profiling I realized that the execution takes about 35% of the time executing the built-in functions [equal?](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Equality.html) and [member](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/List-Searching.html).

My question is regarding whether there exist more efficient version of those functions or I should re-factor the code in order to remove its calls?

I'm about to re-write the code so I would really appreciate any piece of advice.

Thanks!

EDIT 1:

I add some code for making the question clearer. The following function takes two parameters, a pair (x,y) and a term, x and y are usually variable names(symbols), but they may be a symbol and a number, a list and a symbol, etc. The term is a list such as

```
   (+ w y z (* (- 1) x))
```

so after the function execution I would get something like

```
  (+ w z)
```

The code looks like the following:

```
  (define (simp-by-term_eq t_CC t)
   (cond
    ((and (member (list '* (list '- 1) (car t_CC)) (cdr t))
          (member (cadr t_CC) (cdr t)))
      (delete-1st (cadr t_CC) 
        (delete-1st (list '* (list '- 1) (car t_CC)) (cdr t)))
     )

    ((and (member (list '* (car t_CC) (list '- 1)) (cdr t))
          (member (cadr t_CC) (cdr t)))
      (delete-1st (cadr t_CC) 
        (delete-1st (list '* (car t_CC) (list '- 1)) (cdr t)))
    )
    (else t)
     )
    )
```

There are several conditions like the previous one on the function.

The equal function calls are mainly used into filter callse such as

```
  (filter (lambda (x) (and (not (equal? (list '* (car t_CC) (list '- 1)) x))
                           (not (equal? (list '* (list '- 1) (car t_CC)) x)))) t)
```

Answer (score 3):

`equal?` needs to test every part of list structure so basically it traverses both operands until it has touched all sequences and compared all atomic values. If you need to test if it's the same you can use `eq?` which only checks that the pair has the same address. Thus it will evaluate to `#f` even when the list structure look the same. Sometimes that's ok. `eqv?` is similar to `eq?` but it also works for numbers and characters (but not strings).

You can use `memq` that uses `eq?` instead of `equal?` and you can use `memqv` that uses `eqv?` which also works for numbers and characters.
I'm not that familiar with Guile but if you have performance issues and are using `member` perhaps you should consider hash tables instead?

It could happen you need to rethink the algorithm you use too if you really need to use `equal?`, but without specific code it's difficult to be more specific.